# Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle - how to add roles without hierarchy to my application

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am creating a web application where I need 2 roles. Medic and Patient. They are connected through a many-to many relation (patients can have several medics and vice versa), and the medic is supposed to be able to see its patient's data, but not edit it.

I am using FOSUserBundle and have followed the documentation on using roles. However, the documentation as I see it does not help me in creating these roles. I tried the security part of symfony2 documentation, but it shows how to create a role hierarchy - not helping in my case.

How do I proceed in solving this issue?

EDIT: To be more precise: The real question is how to add the two roles. Maybe I don't need the groups...

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles

> This role doesn't need to be defined anywhere - you can just start using it.

EDIT: simply do
    $user->addRole("ROLE_MEDIC");

Comment: Notice, when no roles are set, you first need to init roles $user->setRoles(array());

Comment: @artworkadシ are you sure? It seems to work just fine. I have checked in phpMyAdmin and the roles are added.             $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($name);

                

                if($isMedic) {

                    $user->addRole("ROLE_MEDIC");

                }

                else {

                    $user->addRole("ROLE_PATIENT");

                }

                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

Comment: Just stumbled upon that and thought i'd share my comment for future users. 
addRole would add your assigned role to the array of roles(supposedly ROLE_USER by default), therefore you'd have multiple roles for that user.